# Can I create a cfobject from a cfc file located on another server?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I have a ColdFusion problem and I hope you guys can help. We are trying (and playing around with) setting up a couple of code servers that will be used for handling AJAX calls. We would also like to have these servers hold global cfc's for the web site. So we have the web site: `www.mysite.com` and we have the code servers with the domain `code.mysite.com`.

My question is, can I create a cfc that sends out different types of email and save that on the code servers and somehow use `cfobject` or another ColdFusion element to call that mail.cfc?

I have tried to create a mapping using the CF Administrator to `http://code.mysite.com` with the name `/code` but it says it can't find it.

Next I tried to use cfobject, setting the webservice, but I forgot it's not a wsdl so that failed. Anyway I also tried to give cfobject an http path, or calling it with `/code`, but it can't find it.

Any ideas? Does this problem make any sense?

Answer (score 3):

For the applicable functions on the code server, set `access="remote"`.  Then you can create your object from a webservice and use the methods you need.